# Switched to HTTPS from HTTP, now login form won't save login fields?

Tags: php, .htaccess, https

Like the title says, I just launched and made my site redirect to HTTPS at all times with the root `.htaccess` file and some of my users have complained that they used to have their account information autofill the email/password fields on page load and now it is not the case. I am really not sure what is causing this? Any ideas would be great. I can/will provide more information than that but frankly am not sure what to give.

Comment: is it only the first time they login on HTTPS (possible detected as new url), or the auto-fill feature is gone for good?

Comment: Start with your .htaccess code. Also did you confirm this was a continuous or one time issue?

Comment: It is every time they log in, the auto fill feature is no longer there. They can click the field and look at previously entered entries and when they select email their email and password are autofilled, but the entries are not present on page load as they were before